# Submit form with submit button not other buttons on page

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to have more than one button on my page but for some reason every button submits my page to the next page. Is there a way to make only my submit button submit and my other buttons only do the functions there set up for?

```
<form name="generatereport" method="post" action="_location_queries.cfm">

<select name="Location" id="loc" multiple="multiple">
    <!---<option selected value="">Select location</option>--->
    <option value="OPERATIONS">Operations</option>
    <option value="CCC">Contact Center</option>
    <option value="QA">QA Department</option>
    <option value="DS">DeSoto</option>
    <option value="PS">Palma Sola</option>
    <option value="LWR">Lakewood Ranch</option>
    <option value="NR">North River</option>
    <option value="SDL">SDL</option>
</select>

<button id="add">ADD ALL</button>
<button id="rem">REMOVE ALL</button>
<br /><br />

<input type="submit"  name="submit" value="Continue" />

</form> 

<script type="text/javascript">
var opts = document.querySelectorAll('#loc option');

document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', function() {
    for ( var i=0; i<opts.length; i++ ) {
        opts[i].selected = true;
    }
});

document.getElementById('rem').addEventListener('click', function() {
    for ( var i=0; i<opts.length; i++ ) {
        opts[i].selected = false;
    }
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Button with no type are interpreted like submit button

add the `type="button"`

```
<button type="button">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

The default type of a button is `submit`, so include a type of `button` and it will not submit the form:

```
<button id="add" type="button">ADD ALL</button>
<button id="rem" type="button">REMOVE ALL</button>
```